# What did Grindelwald mean when he said this?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, gellert-grindelwald

At the end of the movie *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, when Grindelwald is revealed to everyone, he says this to Newt:

> Will we die, just a little?

What does this line mean? Is this some kind of a phrase in English?

Answer (score 13):

### The journey ahead will involve sacrifice

SnitchSeeker asked this question to director David Yates and Eddie Redmayne.

> **What did Grindelwald mean at the end when he told Newt, “Will we die, just a little?” just before he’s taken away?**
>
> **David Yates:** *You know, ultimately, I think that’s what he’s saying there is he’s saying, “We’re gonna be on this amazing journey together, you and I. And it will demand an enormous amount from both of us in what it will put us through. And in that journey, we will probably sacrifice quite a bit. We will lose part of ourselves on the journey. So that’s what that means, I think. Will we die, just a little?*
>
> **Eddie Redmayne:** *It’s almost an invitation. But I think the point is that Newt doesn’t know what that means. But it is so sobering when Johnny [Depp] delivered it because it was this weird invitation that he couldn’t figure out in that moment but I presume he will.*
>
> <sub>[Snitch Seeker - "David Yates, Eddie Redmayne, Dan Fogler talk 'Fantastic Beasts' plot points, Obscurus"](https://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/david-yates-eddie-redmayne-dan-fogler-talk-fantastic-beasts-plot-points-obscurus-106934/)</sub>